# First encryption program

Tags: python, beginner, cryptography

This is the first piece of code that I write that's not just an exercise but a full program I can actually run.

Features:

- Generate random letter/number pairs for each "printable" ASCII character
- Save those pairs in a pickle file
- Encode/decode any string based on that
- Basic user interface

I would greatly appreciate any advice, feedback, comment you can give me on it, as I've been learning programming by myself for a couple months now. Did I structure it right, is it how a program is supposed to be put together, is it commented well and enough?

Also, I realize it's probably a weird way of encrypting anything and there's surely a better/safer/easier way to do encryption but it was mostly an excuse to write the program.

```
from string import printable,\
                   ascii_letters,\
                   ascii_lowercase,\
                   ascii_uppercase
import random
import pickle

def generate_code():
    # Generates a random number for each printable ASCII character,
    # Returns a list of (character, number) tuples for each pair
    characters = printable
    numbers = random.sample(range(len(characters) + 1000), len(characters))
    code = list(zip(characters, numbers))
    return code

def encode(string, code):
    # Replaces each character of string with its code-number
    # and adds a random number of random letters

    coded_string = []
    # find matching number for each character
    for character in string:
        for letter, number in code:
            if character == letter:
                # add the matching number
                coded_string.append(str(number))
                coded_string.append(''.join(
                                        random.sample(
                                            ascii_lowercase,
                                            random.randint(2,6)
                                            )
                                        )
                                   )# random letters used to separate numbers
    for _ in range(random.randrange(len(string))):
        coded_string.insert(
                            random.randrange(len(coded_string)),
                            ''.join(random.sample(
                                          ascii_uppercase, random.randint(1, 3)
                                          ))
                            ) # random uppercase letters randomly inserted
    return ''.join(coded_string)

def decode(string, code):

    def retrieve_letter(n):
        for letter, number in code:
            if int(n) == number:
                return letter
            else:
                continue
        return "No Match found"


    decoded_list = []
    decoded_string = ''
    character = ''
    for item in string:
        if item.isdigit():
            character += item
        else:
            if character != '':
                decoded_list.append(character)
                character = ''
    for n in decoded_list:
        decoded_string += retrieve_letter(n)
    return decoded_string

def save_code(object):
    with open("code.p", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(object, f)

def load_code():
    try:
        with open("code.p", "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No saved code found.")
        return None


def main():

    import time

    code = generate_code()

    print("Welcome to my encryption program!")

    while True: #Code selection menu

        print("Please select an option:")
        print("1: Use saved code")
        print("2: Use new code and overwrite saved code")
        print("3: Use new code and keep saved code")
        prompt = input(">")
        if prompt == "1":
            if load_code() == None:
                code = generate_code()
            else:
                code = load_code()
            break
        elif prompt == "2":
            save_code(code)
            break
        elif prompt == "3":
            break
        else:
            "This option is not available"
            continue

    while True: #Main Loop, asks user if he wants to encode/decode

        print("Would you like to encrypt a phrase?(Y/N)")

        prompt = input(">")
        if prompt in ("N", "no", "No", "n"):
            print("Press Enter to exit or type in anything to continue:")
            prompt = input(">")
            if prompt == '':
                print ("Thank you for using the program, good bye!")
                time.sleep(2)
                break
        else:
            phrase = input("Enter your text here :\n>")
            print (f"\nHere is your code : {encode(phrase, code)}\n")

        print("Would you like to decrypt a phrase?(Y/N)")

        prompt = input(">")
        if prompt in ("N", "no", "No", "n"):
            print("Press Enter to exit or type in anything to continue:")
            prompt = input(">")
            if prompt == '':
                print ("Thank you for using the program, good bye!")
                time.sleep(2)
                break
        else:
            coded_phrase = input("Enter your code here :\n>")
            print(f"\nHere is your original text: {decode(coded_phrase, code)}\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            input("Press Enter to continue")
            print("\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

*Addendum : To help anyone who, like me, knows very little about encryption, I found [this video from the YouTube channel Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMtFhACPnTY).

Here Dr Mike Pound talks about the Secure Hashing Algorithm (SHA1, which however is not a safe encryption algorithm anymore), explaining how it works to create a hash, a seemingly randomly generated string of a fixed length from an input.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congrats on teaching yourself programming! You seem to be doing a good job of it. Aside from the fact that I would not want to use a homebrew crypto algorithm the following should be taken as minimal requirements for being able to rely on this code for productive work:

- The `sleep` calls do not add anything useful. `sleep` should be avoided like the plague in production code.
- I would expect this sort of program to follow some general *nix shell script guidelines:

  - [Read from standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450393/96588) and `print()` reusable data to standard output. So rather than `open("code.p", …)` and `input()` you'd read the input stream, perform decryption or encryption based on [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), and `print()` the reusable data before exiting. In other words, after running something like `./my.py --encrypt --key=password1 < input.txt | ./my.py --decrypt --key=password1 > output.txt` (I don't know what that would look like on Windows, sorry) input.txt and output.txt should be identical.
  - Expose all functionality in a *non-interactive* manner.
- I can't follow the algorithm. I see a lot of mixing of numbers and letters, and what looks like an attempt to obfuscate the ciphertext by adding random length strings to the contents. Some unit tests (or even [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html)) would be very useful to understand how this is meant to be read and understood.
- It's hard to follow two `while True` loops. The first one doesn't even seem to be necessary - it only loops back if the user specifies an invalid option. It would be perfectly valid in this case to exit the program with an error instead.
- Running the code through at least one linter such as `flake8` or `pycodestyle` until it passes both without any warnings will help you create more idiomatic Python. Since you're using Python 3 I would also recommend adding [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html) and running through a strict [`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) configuration such as this one:

  ```
  [mypy]
  check_untyped_defs = true
  disallow_untyped_defs = true
  ignore_missing_imports = true
  no_implicit_optional = true
  warn_redundant_casts = true
  warn_return_any = true
  warn_unused_ignores = true
  ```

Comment: When you say "requirements for putting this code into production" you mean "make it usable by professionals"? Also regarding the while true loops, I wanted to prompt the user again for the same choice if his choice is invalid, how should I do it? And loads of things I've never heard of but thanks a lot, that means I know what to research now!

Comment: I'd consider those kind of the same thing - I think I can use "production" to mean it's performing useful work and can be built on top of, not necessarily that it's on a server answering queries.

Comment: Also : "read from standard input, write to standard output" ? I don't really understand that one. Also I'm on Windows at the moment.